# z-index example on jsfiddle not working, absolutely baffeling

Tags: html, css, z-index

Everything looks like it was done correctly. The 'Loading Image' is supposed to have a lower z-index (be behind of) the image. Why it is not working is beyond me it all looks ok to me.

Have a go at it: https://jsfiddle.net/yjwxdmw3/

```
<div class='img_container' style="position:absolute;left:-100px;top:240px;z-index:1000;">
<div id='loader_container' style='position: absolute;text-align: center;top: 40%;width: 100%;'>
<div id='loader' style='background-color: #ffffff;border: 1px solid #6a6a6a;color: #000000;font-family: Tahoma,Helvetica,sans;font-size: 10px;margin: 0 auto;padding: 10px 0 16px;text-align: left;width: 135px;z-index: 1001;'><div align='center'>Loading image...</div></div></div>
<img style='z-index:1002;' id='imageToggleDef' src='http://cdn.instructables.com/FEB/Q2RO/H9G190RM/FEBQ2ROH9G190RM.LARGE.jpg' /></div>
```

Comment: z-index only works on positioned elements. Image is not positioned so it inherits parent value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the `z-index` on your image isn't applied at all because `z-index` only applies to positioned elements. That means you either have to give the image `position: relative` or `position: absolute` or something like that.

Secondly if you format your code a little bit better it will get a lot easier to understand why the `z-index` stuff is still not working as expected:

```
<div class='img_container' style="position:absolute;left:-100px;top:240px;z-index:1000;">
  <div id='loader_container' style='position: absolute;text-align: center;top: 40%;width: 100%;'>
    <div id='loader' style='background-color: #ffffff;border: 1px solid #6a6a6a;color: #000000;font-family: Tahoma,Helvetica,sans;font-size: 10px;margin: 0 auto;padding: 10px 0 16px;text-align: left;width: 135px;z-index: 1001;'>
      <div align='center'>Loading image...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <img style='z-index:1002;' id='imageToggleDef' src='http://cdn.instructables.com/FEB/Q2RO/H9G190RM/FEBQ2ROH9G190RM.LARGE.jpg' />
</div>
```

With `z-index` you are trying to specify which elements is on top and which is on bottom if two elements overlap. The two concurring elements in your case aren't the image and the #loader but the image and the #loader-container. So you have to give the lower `z-index` to your #loader container. Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/rruj0j3t/1/

If you want to know more about how `z-index` works, MDN has a really in depth guide about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index

Comment: I did not know that. Thank you so much. You solved my hour long problem so eloquently.